# Microsoft SQL Server xml data

Tags: sql-server

[This site](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx) has a technique to pass xml data around in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @productIds xml
SET @productIds ='<Products><id>3</id><id>6</id><id>15</id></Products>' 

SELECT
ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(20)')
FROM @productIds.nodes('/Products/id') as ParamValues(ID)
```

But what is the syntax if I add another field?
The following does NOT work:

```
DECLARE @productIds xml
SET @productIds ='<Products><id>3</id><descr>Three</descr><id>6</id><descr>six</descr><id>15</id><descr>Fifteen</descr></Products>' 

SELECT
ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(20)')
,ParamValues.descr.value('.','VARCHAR(20)')
FROM @productIds.nodes('/Products/id') as ParamValues(ID)
```

Note: Maybe I've constructed my xml wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use something like:

```
SELECT
    ParamValues.ID.value('(id)[1]','VARCHAR(20)'),
    ParamValues.ID.value('(descr)[1]','VARCHAR(20)')
FROM
    @productIds.nodes('/Products') as ParamValues(ID)
```

That FROM statement there defines something like a "virtual table" called `ParamValues.ID` - you need to select the `<Products>` node into that virtual table and then access the properties inside it.

Furthermore, your XML structure is very badly chosen:

```
<Products>
    <id>3</id>
    <descr>Three</descr>
    <id>6</id>
    <descr>six</descr>
    <id>15</id>
    <descr>Fifteen</descr>
</Products>
```

You won't be able to select the individual pairs of id/descr - you should use something more like:

```
<Products>
    <Product>
       <id>3</id>
       <descr>Three</descr>
    </Product>
    <Product>
       <id>6</id>
       <descr>six</descr>
    </Product>
    <Product>
       <id>15</id>
       <descr>Fifteen</descr>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

Then you could retrieve all items using this SQL XML query:

```
SELECT
    ParamValues.ID.value('(id)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS 'ID',
    ParamValues.ID.value('(descr)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS 'Description'
FROM
    @productIds.nodes('/Products/Product') as ParamValues(ID) 

ID    Descrition
 3      Three
 6      six
15      Fifteen
```

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap each set of **id** and **descr** into one parent node. Say **Row**. Now you can access each pair like this.

```
DECLARE @productIds xml
SET @productIds ='<Products><Row><id>3</id><descr>Three</descr></Row><Row><id>6</id><descr>six</descr></Row><Row><id>15</id><descr>Fifteen</descr></Row></Products>' 

SELECT
ParamValues.Row.query('id').value('.','VARCHAR(20)'),
ParamValues.Row.query('descr').value('.','VARCHAR(20)')
FROM @productIds.nodes('/Products/Row') as ParamValues(Row)
```